# installing PMD 6.49.0 to windowsp

Tags: windows, installation, pmd

Download instructions say to install to C:\pmd-bin-6.49.0.
Can this be copied to "C:\Program Files\pmd-bin-6.49.0" instead?
Our network policy generally forbids creating folders off the root.

Thanks, - Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy it into any directory - `C:\pmd-bin-6.49.0` is just an example.
You just need to add a your folder to your PATH environment, e.g. `SET PATH=C:\"Program Files"\pmd-bin-6.49.0\bin;%PATH%`

If you don't want to modify the PATH variable, you can still run PMD by providing the full path, e.g. `C:\"Program Files"\pmd-bin-6.49.0\bin\pmd.bat -d c:\src -R rulesets/java/quickstart.xml -f text`